# Why can I not build create-react-app on ec2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been playing with `create-react-app` for a little bit now on my local machine.  I also create a basic `express` app that I'm running on my `ec2` instance and so I wanted to push my `create-react-app` based project onto the `ec2` and serve the build.  The two commands of interest are `npm run start` and `npm run build`.

Unfortunately when running `npm start` (i believe 'run' isn't necessary for the command actually) on the ec2, I get a ton of errors.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-62-133 ab-site-2017-summer]$ npm start

> ab-site@0.1.0 start /home/ec2-user/ab-site-2017-summer
> react-scripts start

/home/ec2-user/ab-site-2017-summer/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:33
const {
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ab-site@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ab-site@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ec2-user/.npm/_logs/2017-06-26T03_51_22_790Z-debug.log
```

*note*: that  I did notice some problems when `npm install`'ing the `node_modules` for this project on the `ec2`.  I'm also not 100% (as a non-web-dev) whether my fundamental approach here is correct.  My goal is to build the `dist` asset with `npm build` and than point my `express` app to serve the `index.html` file for my domain's index route.   My front-end, through `react-router` should handle all the UI and front-end routing from there.

Comment: What version of npm / node are you running?  Looks like it is complaining about the ES6 destructuring syntax...

Comment: the thing is create-react-app is supposed to abstract that all way by using babel and webpack.  `node -v v4.4.5` `npm -v 5.0.3`

Comment: Yes, create-react-app abstracts away the configuration of these tools for you, the developer, but the environment still needs to support it.  If you look at https://node.green , destructuring features of ES6 aren't supported until 6.4.0, you need to upgrade node running on your EC2 instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [create-react-app README](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/README.md#installation)
, you'll need to have Node >= 6 installed on your EC2 instance in order to build and run the app (the poster is using Node 4.4.5).

The error you are seeing is that Node 4 doesn't know how to handle ES6 destructuring syntax, which wasn't introduced until Node 6.4.0 (see http://node.green).